# System for storing Geometric Data for use in a WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, database, spatial

I'm writing a WPF app that uses thousands of WPF shapes.  What is the most efficient method to store a large number of polygon coordinates for use in WPF?

XML, Database, Binary File, XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does efficiency mean to you? Speed? Storage?

Either way XML is definitely out of the question in both terms of speed and space.

I'll cast my vote for the database route, more specifically a local [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) DB. It's fast, reliable and would be less tedious than creating your own custom binary format.

Comment: The problem is getting the polygon coordinates into memory.  I was thinking the DB route might be fastest.  IF I were to just serialize a List<Shape> to a binary file how would that perform.  Storage space is not an issue.

Comment: Binary serialization via the BinaryFormatter will not be an option because niether the shape classes or geometry classes are marked as serializable. Furthermore, they are sealed classes so you couldn't even subclass and make the subclass serializable. You could give xml serialization a shot, but it is by no means going to be the best performing option because the xml parsing & reflection

Comment: Didn't know that Shape didn't implement serializable.  How does XAML work.  Does it just get complied?  That would probably be the most efficient, but there are other drawbacks.